# How to use a sass $ declaration in useEffect (jsx?)

Tags: reactjs, sass, jsx, use-effect

I have different styles set in a _variables.scss file. like

```
$secondary: #ffc500;
$tertiary: #ffdd69;
$quartiary: #fffbed;
```

I want to use different body colors so I want to change the body background in different pages like so:

```
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"  });
```

this works nicely but now i want to use for example $primary instead of 'red'
I just can't make it work. does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sass `:export` keyword to pass variables from sass files to js files:

```
// colors.scss
$primary: #123456;
:export {
  primary: $primary;
}
```

```
// main.js
import colors from './colors.scss'

colors.primary; // '#123456'
```

As far as I know this is a non-standard keyword, it is handled by webpack + sass-loader, but not all sass transpilers.